# How to adjust the height of a progress bar in Storyboard iOS?

Tags: ios

I just want to adjust the height of a progress bar in storyboard to 10.
I tried to adjust it programmatically but it didn't work, so I want a easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You just follow this:

1. Add a view in the storyboard and set a constraint equal to 10 for the height. Set the constraints for the top, bottom, left and right as you want;
2. Include the progress bar right inside this view with the constraints for the top, bottom, left and right equal to 0.

Now it should work!